# The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a command line for my game in Unity and when adding system information commands like memory I encountered this problem. I hope the community can help me. Thanks in advance. The errors occur at lines 216, 223, and 225.

```
    using UnityEngine;

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    public delegate void CommandHandler(string[] args);

    public class ConsoleController {

#region Event declarations
// Used to communicate with ConsoleView
public delegate void LogChangedHandler(string[] log);
public event LogChangedHandler logChanged;

public delegate void VisibilityChangedHandler(bool visible);
public event VisibilityChangedHandler visibilityChanged;
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Object to hold information about each command
/// </summary>
class CommandRegistration {
    public string command { get; private set; }
    public CommandHandler handler { get; private set; }
    public string help { get; private set; }

    public CommandRegistration(string command, CommandHandler handler, string help) {
        this.command = command;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.help = help;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// How many log lines should be retained?
/// Note that strings submitted to appendLogLine with embedded newlines will be counted as a single line.
/// </summary>
const int scrollbackSize = 20;

Queue<string> scrollback = new Queue<string>(scrollbackSize);
List<string> commandHistory = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, CommandRegistration> commands = new Dictionary<string, CommandRegistration>();

public string[] log { get; private set; } //Copy of scrollback as an array for easier use by ConsoleView

const string repeatCmdName = "!!"; //Name of the repeat command, constant since it needs to skip these if they are in the command history

public ConsoleController() {
    //When adding commands, you must add a call below to registerCommand() with its name, implementation method, and help text.
    registerCommand("babble", babble, "Example command that demonstrates how to parse arguments. babble [word] [# of times to repeat]");
    registerCommand("echo", echo, "echoes arguments back as array (for testing argument parser)");
    registerCommand("help", help, "Print this help.");
    registerCommand("hide", hide, "Hide the console.");
    registerCommand(repeatCmdName, repeatCommand, "Repeat last command.");
    registerCommand("reload", reload, "Reload game.");
    registerCommand("resetprefs", resetPrefs, "Reset & saves PlayerPrefs.");
    registerCommand("ver", ver, "Displays the current game version.");
    registerCommand("buildver", buildver, "Displays the current build.");
    registerCommand("sys", sys, "Displays basic system information.");
    registerCommand("devinfo", devinfo, "Displays important developer information.");
}

void registerCommand(string command, CommandHandler handler, string help) {
    commands.Add(command, new CommandRegistration(command, handler, help));
}

public void appendLogLine(string line) {
    Debug.Log(line);

    if (scrollback.Count >= ConsoleController.scrollbackSize) {
        scrollback.Dequeue();
    }
    scrollback.Enqueue(line);

    log = scrollback.ToArray();
    if (logChanged != null) {
        logChanged(log);
    }
}

public void runCommandString(string commandString) {
    appendLogLine("$ " + commandString);

    string[] commandSplit = parseArguments(commandString);
    string[] args = new string[0];
    if (commandSplit.Length < 1) {
        appendLogLine(string.Format("Unable to process command '{0}'", commandString));
        return;

    }  else if (commandSplit.Length >= 2) {
        int numArgs = commandSplit.Length - 1;
        args = new string[numArgs];
        Array.Copy(commandSplit, 1, args, 0, numArgs);
    }
    runCommand(commandSplit[0].ToLower(), args);
    commandHistory.Add(commandString);
}

public void runCommand(string command, string[] args) {
    CommandRegistration reg = null;
    if (!commands.TryGetValue(command, out reg)) {
        appendLogLine(string.Format("Unknown command '{0}', type 'help' for list.", command));
    }  else {
        if (reg.handler == null) {
            appendLogLine(string.Format("Unable to process command '{0}', handler was null.", command));
        }  else {
            reg.handler(args);
        }
    }
}

static string[] parseArguments(string commandString)
{
    LinkedList<char> parmChars = new LinkedList<char>(commandString.ToCharArray());
    bool inQuote = false;
    var node = parmChars.First;
    while (node != null)
    {
        var next = node.Next;
        if (node.Value == '"') {
            inQuote = !inQuote;
            parmChars.Remove(node);
        }
        if (!inQuote && node.Value == ' ') {
            node.Value = '\n';
        }
        node = next;
    }
    char[] parmCharsArr = new char[parmChars.Count];
    parmChars.CopyTo(parmCharsArr, 0);
    return (new string(parmCharsArr)).Split(new char[] {'\n'} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

#region Command handlers
//Implement new commands in this region of the file.

/// <summary>
/// A test command to demonstrate argument checking/parsing.
/// Will repeat the given word a specified number of times.
/// </summary>
void babble(string[] args) {
    if (args.Length < 2) {
        appendLogLine("Expected 2 arguments.");
        return;
    }
    string text = args[0];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
        appendLogLine("Expected arg1 to be text.");
    }  else {
        int repeat = 0;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(args[1], out repeat)) {
            appendLogLine("Expected an integer for arg2.");
        }  else {
            for(int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i) {
                appendLogLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", text, i));
            }
        }
    }
}

void echo(string[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0},", arg);
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    appendLogLine(sb.ToString());
}

void help(string[] args) {
    foreach(CommandRegistration reg in commands.Values) {
        appendLogLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reg.command, reg.help));
    }
}

void hide(string[] args) {
    if (visibilityChanged != null) {
        visibilityChanged(false);
    }
}

void repeatCommand(string[] args) {
    for (int cmdIdx = commandHistory.Count - 1; cmdIdx >= 0; --cmdIdx) {
        string cmd = commandHistory[cmdIdx];
        if (String.Equals(repeatCmdName, cmd)) {
            continue;
        }
        runCommandString(cmd);
        break;
    }
}

void reload(string[] args) {
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}

void resetPrefs(string[] args) {
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}

void ver(string[] args) {
        appendLogLine("La Llorona 16w14~");
}
void buildver(string[] args)
{
    appendLogLine("Build 040916.04");
}

void sys(string[] args)
{
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.operatingSystem);
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.processorType);
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.systemMemorySize);
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName);
}

void devinfo(string[] args)
{
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.deviceModel);
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.deviceType);
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName);
    appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize);

}

#endregion
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appendLogLine` takes **string** as the parameter but you are passing **int** to it with `appendLogLine(SystemInfo.systemMemorySize);`, `appendLogLine(SystemInfo.deviceType);` and `appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize);`

You have to convert those integers to strings with `ToString()`. So those lines should be

```
 appendLogLine(SystemInfo.systemMemorySize.ToString());
 appendLogLine(SystemInfo.deviceType.ToString());
 appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize.ToString());
```

Also,  `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);` is **deprecated** so include `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` at the **top** then change `Application.LoadLevel` to

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

The fixed version of your code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public delegate void CommandHandler(string[] args);

public class ConsoleController
{

    #region Event declarations
    // Used to communicate with ConsoleView
    public delegate void LogChangedHandler(string[] log);
    public event LogChangedHandler logChanged;

    public delegate void VisibilityChangedHandler(bool visible);
    public event VisibilityChangedHandler visibilityChanged;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Object to hold information about each command
    /// </summary>
    class CommandRegistration
    {
        public string command { get; private set; }
        public CommandHandler handler { get; private set; }
        public string help { get; private set; }

        public CommandRegistration(string command, CommandHandler handler, string help)
        {
            this.command = command;
            this.handler = handler;
            this.help = help;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// How many log lines should be retained?
    /// Note that strings submitted to appendLogLine with embedded newlines will be counted as a single line.
    /// </summary>
    const int scrollbackSize = 20;

    Queue<string> scrollback = new Queue<string>(scrollbackSize);
    List<string> commandHistory = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, CommandRegistration> commands = new Dictionary<string, CommandRegistration>();

    public string[] log { get; private set; } //Copy of scrollback as an array for easier use by ConsoleView

    const string repeatCmdName = "!!"; //Name of the repeat command, constant since it needs to skip these if they are in the command history

    public ConsoleController()
    {
        //When adding commands, you must add a call below to registerCommand() with its name, implementation method, and help text.
        registerCommand("babble", babble, "Example command that demonstrates how to parse arguments. babble [word] [# of times to repeat]");
        registerCommand("echo", echo, "echoes arguments back as array (for testing argument parser)");
        registerCommand("help", help, "Print this help.");
        registerCommand("hide", hide, "Hide the console.");
        registerCommand(repeatCmdName, repeatCommand, "Repeat last command.");
        registerCommand("reload", reload, "Reload game.");
        registerCommand("resetprefs", resetPrefs, "Reset & saves PlayerPrefs.");
        registerCommand("ver", ver, "Displays the current game version.");
        registerCommand("buildver", buildver, "Displays the current build.");
        registerCommand("sys", sys, "Displays basic system information.");
        registerCommand("devinfo", devinfo, "Displays important developer information.");
    }

    void registerCommand(string command, CommandHandler handler, string help)
    {
        commands.Add(command, new CommandRegistration(command, handler, help));
    }

    public void appendLogLine(string line)
    {
        Debug.Log(line);

        if (scrollback.Count >= ConsoleController.scrollbackSize)
        {
            scrollback.Dequeue();
        }
        scrollback.Enqueue(line);

        log = scrollback.ToArray();
        if (logChanged != null)
        {
            logChanged(log);
        }
    }

    public void runCommandString(string commandString)
    {
        appendLogLine("$ " + commandString);

        string[] commandSplit = parseArguments(commandString);
        string[] args = new string[0];
        if (commandSplit.Length < 1)
        {
            appendLogLine(string.Format("Unable to process command '{0}'", commandString));
            return;

        }
        else if (commandSplit.Length >= 2)
        {
            int numArgs = commandSplit.Length - 1;
            args = new string[numArgs];
            Array.Copy(commandSplit, 1, args, 0, numArgs);
        }
        runCommand(commandSplit[0].ToLower(), args);
        commandHistory.Add(commandString);
    }

    public void runCommand(string command, string[] args)
    {
        CommandRegistration reg = null;
        if (!commands.TryGetValue(command, out reg))
        {
            appendLogLine(string.Format("Unknown command '{0}', type 'help' for list.", command));
        }
        else
        {
            if (reg.handler == null)
            {
                appendLogLine(string.Format("Unable to process command '{0}', handler was null.", command));
            }
            else
            {
                reg.handler(args);
            }
        }
    }

    static string[] parseArguments(string commandString)
    {
        LinkedList<char> parmChars = new LinkedList<char>(commandString.ToCharArray());
        bool inQuote = false;
        var node = parmChars.First;
        while (node != null)
        {
            var next = node.Next;
            if (node.Value == '"')
            {
                inQuote = !inQuote;
                parmChars.Remove(node);
            }
            if (!inQuote && node.Value == ' ')
            {
                node.Value = '\n';
            }
            node = next;
        }
        char[] parmCharsArr = new char[parmChars.Count];
        parmChars.CopyTo(parmCharsArr, 0);
        return (new string(parmCharsArr)).Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    #region Command handlers
    //Implement new commands in this region of the file.

    /// <summary>
    /// A test command to demonstrate argument checking/parsing.
    /// Will repeat the given word a specified number of times.
    /// </summary>
    void babble(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            appendLogLine("Expected 2 arguments.");
            return;
        }
        string text = args[0];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            appendLogLine("Expected arg1 to be text.");
        }
        else
        {
            int repeat = 0;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(args[1], out repeat))
            {
                appendLogLine("Expected an integer for arg2.");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)
                {
                    appendLogLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", text, i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void echo(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0},", arg);
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        appendLogLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    void help(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (CommandRegistration reg in commands.Values)
        {
            appendLogLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reg.command, reg.help));
        }
    }

    void hide(string[] args)
    {
        if (visibilityChanged != null)
        {
            visibilityChanged(false);
        }
    }

    void repeatCommand(string[] args)
    {
        for (int cmdIdx = commandHistory.Count - 1; cmdIdx >= 0; --cmdIdx)
        {
            string cmd = commandHistory[cmdIdx];
            if (String.Equals(repeatCmdName, cmd))
            {
                continue;
            }
            runCommandString(cmd);
            break;
        }
    }

    void reload(string[] args)
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    void resetPrefs(string[] args)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    void ver(string[] args)
    {
        appendLogLine("La Llorona 16w14~");
    }
    void buildver(string[] args)
    {
        appendLogLine("Build 040916.04");
    }

    void sys(string[] args)
    {
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.operatingSystem);
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.processorType);
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.systemMemorySize.ToString());
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName);
    }

    void devinfo(string[] args)
    {
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.deviceModel);
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.deviceType.ToString());
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName);
        appendLogLine(SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize.ToString());

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, you can accept it as the solution.